# Switching from battery to desktop power supply?

Tags: power-supply, dc, battery-operated

Is there a rule of thumb or calculator anywhere that can be used to calculate voltage and current provided by a certain number of batteries and what to set a desktop power supply to?

For example 2x AA in series = 3v and 500 mA ? 1A? 5A? ...?

Taking Energizers version of the [LR6](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alk-power-aa.pdf),

```
nominal voltage : 1.5V 
internal resistance : 150 to 300 milliOhms. 

V = IR
I = V/R 
I = 1.5 V/300 mlliOhms 
I = 0.005 A or 500 mA
```

Stringing batteries in series increases the voltage, but not the current supplied.

Would selecting 3V @ 1A on the power supply cause damage to any of the circuit components?

tl;dr : what settings should be used on a bench PSU?

Comment: When in voltage mode, the current setting on a bench supply is a current **limit**. You may want to read about "voltage sources" and "current sources" to clear up any misunderstandings you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alkaline battery has a large range of voltages, 1.5 to 0.9V. You could use any of these voltages in the 1.5V to 0.9V range to power a one cell device or double the voltage for a two cell (ect). A bench supply with a steady voltage is much better than a battery and battery powered devices can handle a wide range of voltages.

[image]
Source: https://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm

Answer (score 1):

Batteries deliver current on demand. The current is determined by the load. A 3V 1A power supply will work. A higher voltage is a problem, because the power supply generates the voltage. The load creates the current in response to the voltage applied an it’s own resistance. (Ohm’s Law)